# how to have space between two specific columns in p:datatable

Tags: css, primefaces

I want some space between multiple columns of p:datatable .How can I achieve it without adding any extra blank column in between

Comment: Look what generated CLIENT SIDE html is and play with the css via your browser developer tool. It's a plain table...

Comment: What do you mean with "multiple columns"? Do you want space between all columns or between specific column pairs?

Comment: between specific column pairs

Answer (score 1):

A guess, I haven't tried it

```
.ui-datatable.padding-third-col tbody tr td:nth-child(3) {
    padding-right: 5px;
}
```

Give the datatable `styleClass="padding-third-col"`.

Edit: sorry does'nt work for me either. I guess it depends on your theme/styling.

I would just make an extra column like

```
<p:column styleClass="hidden" style="width: 20px"></p:column>
```

with

```
.hidden {
    background-color: white;
}
```

For me, its not enough to give it `visibility: hidden` as the row's background shows. Also I need to reset all the borders with something like

```
table[role=grid], tr, td, th {
    border: none !important;
    border-collapse: separate;
}
```

Prefix with the table's styleClass if you like.

[image]

Comment: Works for me. If table width is set to 100% I think it's better to (also) set the column width.

Comment: The edit is not "without adding any extra blank column in between".

Answer (score 0):

Try This Css

```
.ui-datatable tbody td {
    border-color: inherit;
    width: 48px;
    overflow: hidden;
    display: inline-block;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: not working..rather all datatable content is coming in one single column

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your p:datatable elements are inside a

`<div class="container"> <p:datatable class="data">... </div>`

You could change the style of specific p:datatable by:

```css
.container .data:nth-child(n+1){
  color:red;
}
```